# Preventing Replay Attacks in Google Apigee

Tags: apigee, replay, server-side-attacks

We are working on a payment service where we want to make sure that a request to the service is not being replayed, whether on purpose or accidentally. We are going to be using Google Apigee as our API gateway. Is there some policy or configuration setting so that we can set this up in Apigee itself? We are hoping to avoid having to code this in our services.

I am finding some hits on Google with "Apigee" and "replay attack", but they just include the term in a sentence, and then never explain how Apigee does it or how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Apigee itself implements really good security to your APIs, but they also have a product [Apigee Sense](https://docs.apigee.com/sense/what-apigee-sense) that you should take a look. As a recommendation, for your API proxies, you should include the [Spike Arrest policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/spike-arrest-policy) it will help in prevent misuse or attacks.

Hope this helps,
Regards.